# How to get a unique id from a Kubernetes or Openshift cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm looking for a way to uniquely identify a cluster:

- Something that can't be moved to another cluster such as a secret
- Something that can be accessed by the application (e.g. an environment variable or stored in an object that can populate env vars
- Something that is unlikely to change over time for a given cluster.

What would that something be?

Comment: k8s api-server ssl certificate will most likely be the same all the time (or at least until you change it or will be forced to change it because it is expired). Try this: `echo | openssl s_client -connect kubernetes:443 2>&1 | openssl x509 -outform pem` to get the certificate.

Comment: Let me know it this answers your question

Answer (score 2):

With OpenShift 4.x, you can find the unique Cluster ID for each cluster in the `clusterversion` CRD:

```
$ oc get clusterversion -o jsonpath='{.items[].spec.clusterID}{"\n"}'
```

The `clusterversion` object looks like this:

```
$ oc get clusterversion version -o yaml

apiVersion: config.openshift.io/v1
kind: ClusterVersion
metadata:
  name: version
  [..]
spec:
  channel: stable-4.4
  clusterID: 990f7ab8-109b-4c95-8480-2bd1deec55ff
[..]
```

Source: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/support/gathering-cluster-data.html#support-get-cluster-id_gathering-cluster-data